# WebSocket em java e javascript

Tags: javascript, java, websocket, google-chrome-extensão

Tenho um **servidor simples** feito em **JAVA** que **completa um formulário** de um determinado **site** da web. Eu utilizo a **aplicação em JAVA** como servidor para mandar as informações e uma **extensão feita para o Chrome** que age como **cliente**, recebendo essas informações e as colocando no **form do site**.

Meu problema é que quando **fecho a página** e abro novamente ou a atualizo, o **servidor para de enviar** novas informações a ela, gostaria de uma solução se possível, obrigado.

Estou executando a aplicação em **JAVA** através de outra classe main, pelo comando: **new ServidorExt(8080).start();**

**Servidor *JAVA***:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package servidor;

import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import org.java_websocket.WebSocket;
import org.java_websocket.handshake.ClientHandshake;
import org.java_websocket.server.WebSocketServer;
import view.painelUsuarios;

/**
 *
 * @author Neto
 */
public class ServidorExt extends WebSocketServer {

//Pega as informações contidas em outra classe

    public static String msg1;
    public static String msg2;
    public static String msg3;

    public void Verificador() {
        painelUsuarios pu = new painelUsuarios();
        msg1 = pu.getMsg1();
    }

    public void PegaMsg1() {
        msg1 = painelUsuarios.getMsg1();
    }

    public void PegaMsg2() {
        msg2 = painelUsuarios.getMsg2();
    }

    public void PegaMsg3() {
        msg3 = painelUsuarios.getMsg3();
    }

    public ServidorExt(int porta) throws UnknownHostException {
        super(new InetSocketAddress(porta));
        System.out.println("Recebendo conexões da porta: " + porta);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessage(WebSocket webSocket, String mensagem) {

    //Verifica se há novas mensagens para continuar ou dar inicio ao fluxo

        String msgAnterior = "";
        String msgNova;

        while (true) {

            Verificador();
            msgNova = msg1;

            while (!msgNova.equals(msgAnterior)) {
                Verificador();
                msgAnterior = msg1;

                PegaMsg1();
                webSocket.send(msg1);
                System.out.println("msg 1 = "+ mensagem);

                PegaMsg2();
                webSocket.send(msg2);
                System.out.println("msg 2 = "+ mensagem);

                PegaMsg3();
                webSocket.send(msg3);
                System.out.println("msg 3 = "+ mensagem);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClose(WebSocket arg0, int arg1, String arg2, boolean arg3) {
        System.out.println("A conexão foi encerrada.");
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(WebSocket arg0, Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Erro de conexão." + e);
    }

    @Override
    public void onOpen(WebSocket webSocket, ClientHandshake arg1) {
        System.out.println("Foi iniciado uma nova conexão.");
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        System.out.println("Servidor iniciado com sucesso!");
    }

}
```

**Cliente *JavaScript***:

```
/* global websocket, ws */

var ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080');
var itens = [];

ws.onopen = function ()
{
   ws.send("");
   // alert("Mensagem enviada...");
};

ws.onerror = function (erro)
{
    alert('Ocorreu um erro!' + erro);
};

ws.onmessage = function (evt)
{   

//Recebe as mensagens do servidor, as guarda em uma Array e distribui entre 
//as partes do form

    itens.push(evt.data);

    document.getElementById("NI").value = itens[0].toString();

    document.getElementById("CodigoAcesso").value = itens[1].toString();

    document.getElementById("Senha").value = itens[2].toString();

    itens.splice(0,itens.length);
};

ws.onclose = function (evt)
{
    websocket.close();
    alert('Conexão fechada...' + evt);
};

window.onbeforeunload = function (evt) {
    alert('Conexão fechada...' + evt);
    websocket.close();
};
```

***Ps: Não estou recebendo erros no aplicativo ou na extensão do chrome.***

Answer (score 0):

Sem conhecer o resto do seu projeto é complicado dar sugestões de como corrigir, porém o erro esta certamente no seguinte trecho de código:

```
  @Override
public void onMessage(WebSocket webSocket, String mensagem) {

//Verifica se há novas mensagens para continuar ou dar inicio ao fluxo

    String msgAnterior = "";
    String msgNova;

    while (true) {

        Verificador();
        msgNova = msg1;

        while (!msgNova.equals(msgAnterior)) {
            Verificador();
            msgAnterior = msg1;

            PegaMsg1();
            webSocket.send(msg1);
            System.out.println("msg 1 = "+ mensagem);

            PegaMsg2();
            webSocket.send(msg2);
            System.out.println("msg 2 = "+ mensagem);

            PegaMsg3();
            webSocket.send(msg3);
            System.out.println("msg 3 = "+ mensagem);
        }
    }
}
```

Experimente no lugar disto fazer algo como:

```
  @Override
public void onMessage(WebSocket webSocket, String mensagem) {

//Verifica se há novas mensagens para continuar ou dar inicio ao fluxo

    String msgAnterior = "";
    String msgNova;

        Verificador();
        msgNova = msg1;

            Verificador();
            msgAnterior = msg1;

            PegaMsg1();
            webSocket.send(msg1);
            System.out.println("msg 1 = "+ mensagem);

            PegaMsg2();
            webSocket.send(msg2);
            System.out.println("msg 2 = "+ mensagem);

            PegaMsg3();
            webSocket.send(msg3);
            System.out.println("msg 3 = "+ mensagem);
}
```

Não se pode travar a sua Thread com while true (sem condição de saída), você no lugar do while deve produzir um gerenciador para enviar as mensagens para o seu cliente. É bom também produzir um protocolo de mensagens para você saber o que fazer com a mensagem. Repare que você não utiliza a mensagem recebida para nada, apenas para imprimir no log.